# Customizing csv output in htsql

Tags: python, sql, htsql

I would like to know if somebody knows a way to customize the csv output in **htsql**, and especially the delimiter and the encoding ?

I would like to avoid iterating over each result and find a way through configuration and/or extensions.

Thank in advance.

Anthony

Comment: I'm curious what encoding/delimiter you need and why you need it (compatibility with ...).  We have a very pluggable extension mechanism, so there may be lots of options, for example, writing a formatter more specific (and helpful) to the program you are interfacing with.

Comment: Our need is for non-english Excel user where using latin-1 do not request any action while opening the file, whereas utf-8 may display wrong character and request to choose the encoding. Delimiter is ";" as it is the customer default. (else if not ";", Excel will request to explicitly validate your delimiter choice).

Is there any documentation on how to write a custom formatter and plug it or should I dig in the code? Can you suggest a starting point?  Thanks anyway for your quick feedback.

Comment: Perhaps it might be useful for us to support 'xls' formatter for Excel using xlwt, would that solve the problem out of the gate?  This might also provide a good example for writing a formatter. I'll write a blog entry in the next few weeks on custom formatters.
Since we've not yet released 2.3.1 which completely re-does how formatters work (its on hold for documentation), so if you're going to play with formatters... please use tip at bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/prometheus/htsql/overview

Comment: I just managed to write my custom extension implementing a custom bind, format and etc. But I changed htsql source code to do that. Is there a proper way to define the binding outside htsql itself? Through an extension maybe?

Comment: trez: In the htsql implementation (almost) everything is an extension, so yes, it should be certainly possible, if not easy to do -- there are some demo extensions. I admit this isn't well documented though, I'll add that to my priority list.

Answer (score 3):

If you want TAB as a delimiter, use **tsv** format (e.g. /query/:tsv instead of /query/:csv).

There is no way to specify the encoding other than UTF-8.  You can reencode the output manually on the client.